# Last Occurrence of a character in a String in a CL

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

I have a requirement to find the last occurrence of a character in a  string in CL. For Example, If I have a string as `Test_01_abc.Txt` , and I have to get the last occurrence of '_'(Underscore), I need to get answer as 8(Which is the position of the second Underscore in the string).
I am using 7.2 Version and %SCANR is not working here. One way is to go in a loop and search it. Is there a better way?
THanks

Answer (score 1):

`%SCANR` is an RPGLE built in function, not CLP. However, given that you are at v7.2, your only choce is to put `QCLSCAN` in a loop and find the last occurrance that way. There might be a way to do what you want in `Python` if you are willing to use that rather than CL.

Comment: Thanks Mark.. I have never used QCLSCAN API.. But here I can do the %SCAN and run it in a loop to get the last position..  is QCLSCAN any different? Kindly Advise..

Comment: Looks like they have added quite a few built in functions for CL. %SCAN looks similar to QCLSCAN except QCLSCAN has a few more features like wildcard search, and replace capability. Still %SCANR is not an option for CLP even at v7.3.

Comment: Thanks Mark! That helps